# Handling the return value of .NET Socket's EndSend in callback when multiple buffers are used (Scatter/Gathering)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I want to port my TCP server to be using [BeginSend(IList < ArraySegment < Byte >>, SocketFlags, AsyncCallback, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38dxf7kt(v=vs.110).aspx)/EndSend (scatter/gathering with multiple buffers instead of single-buffer version of BeginSend), to reduce the amount of memory allocations and copy operations. I still might use `BeginSend(Byte[], Int32, Int32, SocketFlags, AsyncCallback, Object)` to send the packet header, but the actual content of the packet is an another story - there are a lot of large chunks of cached data, and they might overlap with each other. Currently, i'm allocating a very large buffer and than copying those chunks to that buffer. Definately, it isn't a great idea and i want to explicitly reuse already allocated and cached chunks of data.

[BeginSend(IList < ArraySegment < Byte >>, SocketFlags, AsyncCallback, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38dxf7kt(v=vs.110).aspx) looks useful for such purpose, but i do not know how to handle the return value of EndSend in callback:

```
// ... 
// This method will allocate header, set the opcode and total length of the
// packet, than create a list of array segments to hold header and each chunk
// buffer
var packetBuffer = PacketFactory.GetPacketBuffer(opcode, chunks, _socket);
_socket.BeginSend(packetBuffer.Buffers, SocketFlags.None, OnSendComplete, packetBuffer);
// ...
// in OnSendComplete
var buffer = ar.AsyncState as PacketBuffer;
try
{
  int bytesReceived = buffer.Socket.EndSend(ar);
  if (bytesReceived > 0)
  {
     // It is possible this value is less than total size of my buffers?
     // If so, how do i handle it?
     // In case of the single buffer, all i need to do is increase the
     // current buffer position, calculate bytes left and invoke BeginSend
     // once again
  }
}
catch { ... }
```

Could anyone help me or provide a snippet how to use multiple send buffers?

Comment: both links you attached doesn't work .

Comment: Opps, sorry. Should be fine now!

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? I think the code could be simplified and explained more readily by using TPL to abstract the asynchronous processing parts.